# Memory placement of members in a struct

Tags: c

For me this piece of code was unexpected. I would previously in my naivity assume that members of a struct that a decleared in order was placed as,

```
| b1 | b2 | b3 | b4 |
first     second
```

but I think this snippet show that assumption to be false,

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef union {
    struct {
        uint16_t first;
        uint16_t second;
    };
    uint32_t id;
} uuid_t;

int
main(void)
{
    uuid_t uuid;
    uuid.id = 0x11112222;

    assert(uuid.first == 0x1111);
    assert(uuid.second == 0x2222);
}
```

With the correction,

```c
typedef union {
    struct {
        uint16_t second;
        uint16_t first;
    };
    uint32_t id;
} uuid_t;
```

asserts will pass and that doesn't yet makes sense to me. Why is that?

Comment: You might want to read about **endianess**. You are running your program on a little endian machine. Besides that you are invoking undefined behaviour as you read a different member of the union than what was written last.

Comment: When using type-punning between structure, also beware of [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Comment: And of course please read about [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: Yesyesyes, forgot to include the number 0x11112222 into my universe, began to question reality, then I saw the light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems because little-endian is used in your environment.

In little-endian environment, the number `0x11112222` is stored in memory like

```
 <--low      high-->
| 22 | 22 | 11 | 11 |
```

and the structure

```
struct {
    uint16_t first;
    uint16_t second;
};
```

probably be

```
 <--low      high-->
| 22 | 22 | 11 | 11 |
| first   | second  |
```

Therefore `uuid.first` will be `0x2222` and `uuid.second` will be `0x1111` by `uuid.id = 0x11112222;` in the first code.